# Is my sentence 我本来要带你去的，但是我的车抛锚了 correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, writing-critique

I am learning how to use 本来 in a sentence; we are supposed to fill in the sentence to make the conversation whole.  The first sentence is the one I wrote using the 本来 and the second is already given:

> My sentence that I came up with: 我本来要带你去的，但是我的车抛锚了。
>
> Sentence given in question book: 没关系，我从那儿打车回来很方便。

Can someone please check for me? I don't know if my sentence is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the second sentence includes 从**那儿** and 打车**回来** (come back), I would assume the two speakers are in the place they want to come back to, therefore the first person (A) is not 带 "taking" the second person (B) anywhere. She's going to pick her up.
2. I think the main sentence sounds better with 准备, or 想, instead of 要, as it introduces an intent (then disrupted by the car breaking down), instead of a sure thing.

> 我本来准备去接你，但是我的车抛锚了。
>
> I was going to pick you up, but my car broke down.

Comment: 説「想去接你」比較親切一點吧？

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence doesn't really fit the answer given.

Your sentence:

我本来（是）要带你去的，但是我的车抛锚了。
I was gonna take you there, but my carriage conked out!

You:

我本来是要去接你的，但是我的车抛锚了。
I was gonna pick you up, but my carriage conked out!

Reply:

没关系，我从那儿打车回来很方便。
No biggie, it's easy to call a cab to come back.

Answer (score 0):

A say: 我本来要带你去的，但是我的车抛锚了。

B reply: 没关系，我从那儿打车回来很方便。

帶你去 means "take you to somewhere". But the given sentence is 回来, which means COME BACK, GO BACK, RETURN, etc.

So, B wants to go back (e.g home), but your sentence looks like that you are going to pick  B up then go to somewhere else.

Correct:

我本来要"带你回來"的

我本来要"接你回來"的

我本来要"去接你"的, It's more neutural, you can use it like this:

A say: 我本来要"去接你"的，但是我的车抛锚了。

B say: 没关系，我从那儿打车**回来**很方便。.

or

B say: 没关系，我从那儿打车**過去**很方便。 (If it is your given sentence, "我本来要带你去的，但是我的车抛锚了。 is correct.)